# Could chimpanzees be the dominant species

Tags: alternate-history

What if I’m an alternate universe instead of humans, chimpanzees became the most intelligent species.what if after humans and chimpanzees split what if it was the chimpanzees who became intelligent, discovering fire, later agriculture and etc. In this alternate universe would humans basically be the equivalent of chimpanzees in our universe. What if these intelligent chimps migrated to different parts of the world like early humans did. Would they domesticate animals like we did. Would they eventually discover  steam engines, gunpowder, atomic bombs and space travel. To give you a very quick summary of my question I’m asking if chimpanzees became intelligent would their society and tech resemble  ours.

Comment: 8 million years ago there lived a species of apes, which inhabited the borderland between the forest and the savannah. Some of them preferred to live in the savannah, and eventually evolved into humans. Some of them preferred to live in the forest and eventually evolved into chimpanzees. All your question does is call humans chimpanzees and chimpanzees humans; simply switching two words around does not make any change in the actual reality. *We* are those chimpanzees.

Comment: Questions asking "How would X affect society?" are often closed as too broad.

Comment: Philip K. Dick wrote a book around this, where the homo erectus pekinensis was the dominant species. The book is called The crack in space.

Comment: If we completely ignore @AlexP's comment, this question becomes enormously broad.  Besides, how different is this, really, from *The Planet of the Apes?*  (I'm thinking of one of the kinda recent ones with an "Abraham Lincoln" statue sporting a chimp head....)

Comment: @JBH, Apraham Lincoln

Comment: I agree completely with @AlexP above (+1), as the question stands the split is meaningless - one branch becomes humans and the other branch becomes chimpanzees - the way that we notice the difference is because of subsequent evolution, and that is the branch, not between humans and chimpanzees but between different evolutionary paths.

Answer (score 1):

I remember reading that the [difference in genetic makeup](https://news.nationalgeographic.com/news/2005/08/chimps-humans-96-percent-the-same-gene-study-finds/) between Chimpanzees and Humans is about 3% or 4% (depending on the study); normally, we expect to see a difference of more than 7% in DNA before we'd normally call two animals different species but for us the difference is so pronounced that we essentially make an exception in this case.

What that means in essence is that from one perspective, there's not sufficient difference between us as different 'species' to warrant the separation you describe.

Chimpanzees are already reasonably intelligent, social creatures and show the ability to use tools (and train their young to use them too). What they lack by comparison to us is a sophisticated language structure and the ability to easily store and categorise knowledge in a manner that allows them to build on the lessons of the past.

Part of this is due to the shape of the mouth and the larynx; as I understand it, chimpanzees can only verbalise a subset of the range of sounds that we use to communicate. Mind you, their non-verbal communication seems quite solid and it's entirely possible that their emotional intelligence (EQ) is more developed than some humans.

That lack of communication (and the ability to store and retrieve knowledge) is more likely the reason that chimpanzees have not developed along the same lines as humans over intelligence. What that means in terms of your question is that the answer is YES; chimpanzees could have developed along similar lines as us intellectually, but if they did, they would no longer be chimpanzees; they'd be an animal with an ability that chimpanzees currently don't have.

As I've mentioned in another answer, knowledge is cumulative, intelligence is not. Our ability as Humans today is based on cheap (energy wise) access to the wealth of human knowledge built up throughout our history; our intelligence is not that particularly better than it was 10k years ago; what makes us more powerful now is that the intelligence we have is playing with so much more data than it could back then.

Comment: *"What they lack by comparison to us is a sophisticated language structure and the ability to easily store and categorise knowledge in a manner that allows them to build on the lessons of the past"*... And they have a very short attention span; but apparently we are working towards reducing the difference.

Comment: That's a good point @AlexP; IIRC this is being explored around the concept of neuroplasticity. It's entirely possible that their attention span is a factor of the immediacy of their environment and that their minds can change just like ours have since Gutenberg's printing press, with less emphasis on memory and more on functional processing and problem solving.